# use tcpreplay for real trace internet dataset

Tags: dataset, mininet, tcpreplay

I have CAIDA internet trace dataset and it contain more than 200000 unique IPv4 addresses and almost 1 million flows.
Im currently using mininet to emulate my SDN project and i wish that i could use this dataset in my simulation.

What i plan is tou use the Tcpreplay to replay the dataset in my mininet. The question is,
1. Do i have to manually configure more than 200000 unique ipv4 hosts in order to mimic the real network as in the dataset?
2. Or there are another way

Appreciate whoever has this experience of using tcpreplay together with real internet dataset could share the knowledge.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the use **tcpreplay** with the **--unique-ip option**, which will create unique IP addresses for each transmission of the pcap file. This option is very fast, and allows you to run at a controlled rate, all the way up to 10GigE full wire speed.

```
tcpreplay -i eth7 -tK --loop 50 --unique-ip bigFlows.pcap
```

I suggest that you read my article [How to do a Performance Test for an IP Flow Appliance](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/howto.html#how-to-do-a-performance-test-for-an-ip-flow-appliance). Also suggest using my [bigFlows.pcap](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98306176/captures/bigFlows.pcap) file which contains a large capture of actual traffic on a corporate WAN.